# How to provide ventilation on NEMA 12 Arcshield enclosure with help of fans?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a NEMA 12 enclosure with VFD (Powerflex 753) mounted in it. Also the enclosure should be ArcShielded. But the norms are that if the NEMA 12 enclosure is arc proof, then no fans should be mounted on the door ( to avoid the arc fallout on the operating personnel through fans). So how should I provide the ventilation ? The space factor is 6 S.F. ( = 78 inches ). (Please note:- There are fans made especially for ArcShield, but those cannot be mounted on NEMA 12 enclosure.)

Comment: We have a car parking facility at our commercial outlet and it involves panels ( motor control centres). If this irrelevant forum then please direct my question to relevant one

Comment: Maybe the rules are different where you are but most of my enclosures have vfds and 1 or 2 fans, we did have a large one blow a year or so back melted the plastic lovers and filter media. These are what the mfg installed on our enclosures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about home improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There are no NEMA 12 fan options for PowerFlex VFDs in the "100ms" version of ArcShield MCCs, but there are in the "Device Limited" version. Device Limited ArcShield MCCs mean the MCC can have a maximum of 1200A bus and the main must be part of the MCC.

If you have an MCC at 1600A or larger, then you are limited as to which VFD options are available to you and there are no options for NEMA 12 vented VFDs, so that limits you to I think 40A (25HP @ 480V) or 34A (20HP) if there is a reactor, which is the largest non-vented VFD in a NEMA 12 package.

What I do if the project needs larger VFDs in NEMA 12 and needs to be Arc Resistant is to split up the MCCs into 1200A or smaller segments so that I can use Device Limited, which allows for vented VFDs in NEMA 12.

But to answer your specific question, you cannot add ***anything*** to the front doors of an ArcShield MCC in the field without violating the Arc Resistant certification of it.

*Side note: You mentioned "NEMA" so I am assuming you are discussing the 2100 Series NEMA MCCs, not the IEC version 2500 series. Those options may be different for IEC.*

Comment: Ofcourse splitting up the MCC into 1200 Device Limited version is possible. But due to space constraints I can't split up the MCC. There is a slot for bottom entry cable which is dugged previously. Any other solution to how sufficiently ventilate the VFD. Yes, my MCC is 2100 Centerline

Comment: If it is over 1200A, you cannot have vented VFDs in it. Period. There is no option.